Is it feasible to utilize the Confidant application secret keeper by lyft within an Azure environment?
Is it feasible to utilize the Confidant application within an Azure environment? Additionally, are there any documentation resources available for setting it up on Azure? Please share the steps to configure it with Azure, along with any relevant documentation.
Are there any steps or supporting documents to setup the confidant application in Azure platform as this is tied with the AWS and aws kms and dynamo configs are hardcoded in the application.

It's possible to deploy the application to Azure, but not to have the entire solution contained within Azure.
The application relies on KMS, and it's application logic is solely focused on using this. Whereas with Azure, it would need to be rewritten to use KeyVault.

Thank you for the response. It would be beneficial if you could provide detailed information including any documentation and steps to be followed to integrate the confidant application in Azure.

@YuvarajS It's not possible to integrate. It's only possible to deploy the application to Azure Container Services (based on Docker). You would still need AWS KMS. I don't think many people would find the instructions useful.
